# chef verify error invalid!': Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

Tags: chef-infra

getting the error while running the chef verify

```
Running verification for component 'berkshelf'
Running verification for component 'test-kitchen'
Running verification for component 'tk-policyfile-provisioner'
Running verification for component 'chef-client'
Running verification for component 'chef-dk'
Running verification for component 'chef-provisioning'
Running verification for component 'chefspec'
Running verification for component 'generated-cookbooks-pass-chefspec'
Running verification for component 'rubocop'
Running verification for component 'fauxhai'
Running verification for component 'knife-spork'
Running verification for component 'kitchen-vagrant'
Running verification for component 'package installation'
Running verification for component 'openssl'
Running verification for component 'inspec'
................./opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.6/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:289:in `invalid!': Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1' (Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed)
---- Begin output of /usr/local/bin/ohai -v ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'chef-config' (= 12.8.0) - did find: [chef-config-12.7.2] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/saddam/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/ohai:4:in `<main>'
---- End output of /usr/local/bin/ohai -v ----
Ran /usr/local/bin/ohai -v returned 1
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.6/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:276:in `error!'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in `block in sh!'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in `tap'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in `sh!'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/command/verify.rb:358:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Verify>'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:78:in `run_smoke_test'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/command/verify.rb:475:in `block (2 levels) in invoke_tests'
```

I would like to add one more thing I have ruby installed in the latest version of 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update to the latest:

`curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -c current -P chefdk`

per https://github.com/chef/chef-dk

or edit ohai script: `sudo vi /usr/bin/ohai` replacing `12.8.0` with `12.7.2`

per https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/718

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the current Omnibus installer comes bundled with (or expects) the wrong version of chef-config.

Further complicating this is that chef-config-12.8.0 is not yet on rubygems.org

Here's how I worked around it

```
git clone https://github.com/chef/chef.git
cd chef/chef-config
/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem build chef-config.gemspec
/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem install chef-config-12.8.0.gem
```

Comment: Hi @mcourtney i tried it but I am getting the same error . I already have ruby installed for rails. can that be the thing i am getting the error..

Comment: @sk.saddam Installing the latest fixed it for me: curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -c current -P chefdk per https://github.com/chef/chef-dk

Comment: @sk.saddam that is possibly the reason. I have edited my answer to use the gem binary embedded in ChefDK which should resolve your issue

Comment: @awgtek that did it for me as well. You should post it as an alternative answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am getting similar issue :

[root@invalid!': Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1' (Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed)
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/ohai -v ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:into_specs': Could not find 'chef-config' (= 12.8.0) - did find: [chef-config-12.7.2] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/root/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in`gem'
        from /usr/bin/ohai:4:in `<main>'
---- End output of /usr/bin/ohai -v ----
Ran /usr/bin/ohai -v returned 1
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.6/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:276:in`error!'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in `block in sh!'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in`tap'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:99:in `sh!'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/command/verify.rb:358:in`block (2 levels) in '
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/component_test.rb:78:in`run_smoke_test'
        from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-dk-0.11.2/lib/chef-dk/command/verify.rb:475:in `block (2 levels) in invoke_tests'